# Properly using Matlab Watershed Algorithm to segment cells

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, image-segmentation, watershed

I've run into a ton of trouble trying to get the watershed algorithm properly working on my images. In the various tutorials online they always seem to use images that are just as complicated/fuzzy and so I'm not sure what is wrong with mine. I've already made a couple of spotty posts on this, but wanted to really clarify and ask generally. That said, I'm using images like: 
[image]

However, when I attempt to apply one of the watershed algorithms:

```
imshow(RGB,[]);

gray_img = rgb2gray(RGB);
tophat_filter = imtophat(gray_img, strel('disk', 10)); %Read into this

level = graythresh(tophat_filter);
BW = im2bw(tophat_filter,level);
imshow(BW)

BW = bwdist(BW) <= 3;

imshow(BW)
bgn_remove = bwareaopen(BW,8); %remove background noise

D = -bwdist(~bgn_remove); %Read into this
D(~BW) = -Inf;
L = watershed(D);

figure;
imshow(L,[]);
figure;
imshow(label2rgb(L))
clean_img = im2bw(L,0.001);

figure;
imshow(clean_img,[]);
```

It never seems to work. For whatever reason, it determines that each cell consists a bunch of smaller ones:
[image]

I attempted to get around this by clumping the segmeneted components with `BW = bwdist(BW) <= 3;` so that the image isn't AS fragmented:

[image]

As shown in the first image there are supposed to be 3 cells, and while the watershed does recognize two distinct cells on the left- it registers more than it should (even after the clumping).
I haven't made much progress after everything that I've tried, so any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

After going through the full watershed procedure, I end up with maxima like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a seeded/constrained/markers watershed. If you use the classical (not used anymore) watershed, you face an over-segmentation.

In your case, I would do this classic approach to segment the cells using the watershed:

1. Small closing in order to reduce the noise.
2. (optional) Small opening to regularize the cell rims.
3. Erosion. The result of the erosion is your inner marker.
4. Dilation. The result of the dilation is your outer marker.
5. Gradient of the resulting image after step 1 (or 2 if you did it).
6. Watershed on the gradient image (step 5), using the markers (steps 3 and 4).

But in your case with such well defined cells, I would simple do the step 1 and 2, followed by a top-hat. It will be as effective and much faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. However, I'm very new to this and have a couple questions: For step 1, is "small closing" a morphological close like `imclose`? Or rather a close with something like `bwareaopen` for noise reduction? For step 2, is regularize the cell rims to even them out? and if so how would it differ from step 1? I think I understand step 3 and 4 but I'll look into them more. On step 5/6 I'm not sure how I'd preform the watershed using those specific markers- seems to differ from the general case. Is there anyway that you could provide sample code for some of these steps?

Comment: 1/ Yes, inclose does a closing, when bwareaopen does an area opening on black and white images (not your case here). 2/ It's just going to irregular shapes. As I said, it's optional. Step 1 will delete all the dust effect mainly in the middle of the cells, when step 2 after step 1 will affect mainly the contour. 5/6 For the gradient, use Sobel. For the watershed, look for a seeded (also called constrained) version, then the gradient image and the markers will be part of the parameters. And sorry, I don't use MatLab.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Also you mentioned using `tophat`, is there any reason why this would cause the cells to mostly disappear? The image looks much cleaner after using steps 1 and 2, could I potentially use the watershed on those alone? Or would it make much more sense to use the erosion dilation/ or the tophat method first?

Comment: You need erosion and dilation to compute the markers, as you need the gradient in order to have highlighted cell rims. For the Top-Hat, you need to use a BIG structuring element. A structuring element big enough to erase the cells.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I followed your instructions along with http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html but I'm still stuck-- at the end of the process each clump is recognized as one. The step that determines each pair as a single is: `fgm = imregionalmax(Iobrcbr)` which is 'Regional maxima of opening-closing by reconstruction (fgm)'. Any advice how I can lower this threshold or is this sort of a lost cause? Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please post an example of your result?

Comment: The best solution in you case is to: reduce the size of the closing in order to reduce the impact on the border, and then to compute the ultimate eroded. It will give you one center/marker per cell.